# Application has stopped in android simulator

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I'm new in Android Studio and just trying to create a simple application like Collapsing Toolbar Layout, but after I run the program it suddenly stopped I wonder why this is happening? is there any solution for this problem?

here's my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#fcfcfc">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/CollapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:title="App Title"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:background="@drawable/backmaterial">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarid"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                >

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Error log in the logcat :

```
12-26 03:21:10.028 2653-2653/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-26 03:21:10.028 2653-2653/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-26 03:21:10.577 2672-2672/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-26 03:21:10.577 2672-2672/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-26 03:21:13.466 2686-2686/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-26 03:21:13.466 2686-2686/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-26 03:21:14.146 2703-2703/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-26 03:21:14.147 2703-2703/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-26 03:21:14.456 2716-2716/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10062: Read-only file system
12-26 03:21:16.016 2716-2716/com.miyuki.ouka.collapsetollbar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.miyuki.ouka.collapsetollbar, PID: 2716
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.miyuki.ouka.collapsetollbar/com.miyuki.ouka.collapsetollbar.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.miyuki.ouka.collapsetollbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.miyuki.ouka.collapsetollbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.miyuki.ouka.collapsetollbar:drawable/backmaterial" (7f07005d)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f07005d a=-1 r=0x7f07005d}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2390)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3730)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:491)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:115)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:111)
        at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.<init>(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:155)
        at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.<init>(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:151)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.miyuki.ouka.collapsetollbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
12-26 03:21:16.454 535-535/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 535: eglCreateSyncKHR(1215): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
12-26 03:30:31.551 2772-2772/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10062: Read-only file system
12-26 03:30:32.453 2772-2772/com.miyuki.ouka.collapsetollbar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.miyuki.ouka.collapsetollbar, PID: 2772
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.miyuki.ouka.collapsetollbar/com.miyuki.ouka.collapsetollbar.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.miyuki.ouka.collapsetollbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.miyuki.ouka.collapsetollbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.miyuki.ouka.collapsetollbar:drawable/backmaterial" (7f07005d)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f07005d a=-1 r=0x7f07005d}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2390)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3730)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:491)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:115)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:111)
        at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.<init>(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:155)
        at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.<init>(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:151)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.miyuki.ouka.collapsetollbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
12-26 03:30:32.757 560-852/system_process E/ActivityManager: Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 384x384
```

Comment: Have u added dependency for design support library `implementation 'com.android.support:design:x.x.x'`

Comment: yes I have already did that

Comment: this is what I put in my code  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

Comment: most likely `@drawable/backmaterial` does not exist.

Comment: @martin zeitler `@drawable/backmaterial` doesn't cause this error!

Comment: @Gourav of course it does; the stack-trace complains about it. added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

the stack-trace reads:

> Error inflating class `android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout`

and it also reads:

> Caused by: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException`: Resource "com.miyuki.ouka.collapsetollbar:`drawable/backmaterial`" (7f07005d)

the `NotFoundException` can be fixed by either:

- adding the referenced resource file `drawable/backmaterial.xml`
- removing the line `android:background="@drawable/backmaterial"`